# Button does not show icon on most Ubuntu/debian desktops

Tags: python, gtk, gtkbutton

I have an app that has a play button to play audio from some local repeater: Although I want just a play/stop button, the button does not play on newer Ubuntu or a new Raspbian install. Is there something missing here, maybe related to the recent change where they set all the buttons to not show icons on buttons in GTK/Ubuntu?

`button.set_image(Gtk.Image.new_from_stock(Gtk.STOCK_MEDIA_PLAY, self.PLAYSIZE))`

Is this how I should set the button to only have an icon? It works on my 16.04 setup, but button is blank on others. The code is [here](https://github.com/programmin1/Repeater-START/blob/master/src/repeaterstart.py) and app is [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/repeater-start/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gtk::Button with standard Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037055/gtkbutton-with-standard-icons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

button.set_label('') made the button's image hide. It seems that Ubuntu and other systems do not display the icon whenever *any text label is on it*?

Answer (score 1):

Stock icons are deprecated, and should not be used in newly-written code.

The appropriate way to show an icon in a button is to use [named icons](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html) from an icon theme.

For instance, if you want to show a "play" icon, you should use `media-playback-start`:

```py
b = Gtk.Button()
b.set_image(Gtk.Image(icon_name='media-playback-start',
                      icon_size=Gtk.IconSize.BUTTON))
```

Comment: It still doesn't show when I have the "buttons have icons" unchecked... and this is default behavior I believe.

Comment: If you set both the label *and* the image, then the image won't be visible—unless you change the setting. If you want to always show the button's image and text, you'll have to pack a Box with an image and a label inside the Button.